# Proxy Error while using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am trying to use Google Earth Engine (GEE) Python API using the following code:

```
import ee 

#ee.Authenticate()

ee.Initialize()
```

With the above code I am successfully able to Authenticate myself, but in Intialization step I am getting the following error:

```
ProxyError: ('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))
```

I am getting the above error as I am trying to access this API from behind the firewall system. I have added proxy details ("http_proxy", "https_proxy") in my system environment variable in this format 'http://username:password@proxy:port' but still I am getting the above error.

Can someone please suggest me how to overcome this above error.

Comment: I had proxy issues with GEE once; I had to modify the GEE code to include the proxy in the http request: https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/issues/31 Not sure if this will fix your issue.

Comment: Hi @Jon. I tried to incorporate your suggestion in the 'oauth.py' file but still I am getting the same error.